# redux-saga: Запрос выполняется дважды

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

У меня есть actions,reducers,sagas. Следующий код:

Actions types:

```
export const ACTION_TYPES = {
  FETCH_USER_REQUEST: "FETCH_USER_REQUEST",
  FETCH_USER_SUCCESS: "FETCH_USER_SUCCESS",
  FETCH_USER_FAILED: "FETCH_USER_FAILED",
};
```

reducers:

```
export const userData = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "REQUEST_FETCH_USER":
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
      };
    case ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_USER_REQUEST:
      return {
        ...state,
      };
    case ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_USER_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        user: action.payload,
      };
    case ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_USER_FAILED:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        error: action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Actions:

```
export const fetchUser = () => {
  return { type: "REQUEST_FETCH_USER" };
};

export const requestUser = () => {
  return { type: ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_USER_REQUEST };
};

export const requestUserSuccess = (data) => {
  return { type: ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_USER_SUCCESS, payload: data };
};

export const requestUserError = (err) => {
  return { type: ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_USER_FAILED, payload: err };
};
```

Sagas:

```
export function* watcherFetchUser() {
  yield takeEvery("REQUEST_FETCH_USER", workerSagaUser);
}

function* workerSagaUser() {
  yield put(requestUser());
  try {
    const response = yield call(() => {
      return getUser().then((res) => res);
    });
    yield put(requestUserSuccess(response.data));
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(requestUserError(error));
  }
}
```

Далее я в коде просто вызываю `dispatch(fetchUser());`
и вот что получаю:[image: Redux-logs]

Где я перемудрил, что получаю двойной вызов?( Да если я использую `takeLeading` то конечно же всё окей, но я очень хочу понять, почему такое происходит.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка была в создании `store`:

```
const enhancer = composeEnhancers(
  applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware, routerMiddleware(history))
);

export const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  compose(applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware), enhancer)
);
```

Я дважды зарегистрировал `sagaMiddleware`(